# Why is 우 often romanized as "woo"?

Tags: pronunciation, romanisation

Especially with names I have often seen this romanization, but also with other words. [Here is an example](https://www.woorisf.com/news/what-woori-means-in-korean) where the word 우리 is transliterated as "woori". Other examples are the Korean bank "Woori Bank" [(Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woori_Bank) or the korean first name [Hyun-woo (현우)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyun-woo) with its common english spelling.

Why is the "w" at the beginning being used, instead of just "oo"? I would expect "Oori" to come closest in terms of pronunciation when transliterating 우리 to English. Is the correct pronunciation of 우 actually closer to "woo"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I deem that you already know the correct romanization is *u* when you follow  [the official Korean language romanization system](https://www.korean.go.kr/front_eng/roman/roman_01.do). I would say that there are several reasons for using *woo* instead of *oo* and *u*, but others might disagree at some points:

1. **A lot of people want to conform to the custom**. It is an idiomatic transliteration going against the official (standard) rules. Even 노태우, a former president, has used Roh Tae-woo. You should also note that some people use wu, u, oo, wooh, etc. no matter what others use.
2. [양병선](http://www.alskorea.or.kr/NFUpload/nfupload_down.php?tmp_name=20161121145035.1990.4.0&name=%ED%95%A9%EB%B3%B8.pdf) stated that *woo* (/wuː/) should be used for 우 (/u/ or /uː/). He considered that **there are very few English monosyllables starting with *oo* or *u*.** For *oo*, indeed, I can find only a few: oof (/uːf/), oops (/ʊps/), ooh (/uː/), and oomph (/ʊmf/). Furthermore, English dictionaries that I usually consult have *woo* but not *oo*. Thus, the spelling ***woo* should look more familiar and natural** than *oo* (In my opinion, "Woo" looks much better than "Oo"). Although the pronunciation, /wuː/, is slightly different from 우, Koreans can still take it as 우 since no other Korean vowels sound very similar to or the same as /wuː/.
3. When *woo* represents the last Hangul character of a name, **it shows that the character is 우 not others**. For example, 건우 can be written as Gunwoo or Gunoo; in this case, *woo* clearly shows that 우 is included in the name while Gunoo represents either 건우 or 거누.
4. **When a vowel comes before *oo*, it could be difficult to find the syllable boundaries.** As far as I know, using the hyphen is not always allowed. If you write 태우 as Taeoo (not as Taewoo), it is likely to be mispronounced since a, ae, eo, and o represent 아 (ㅏ), 애 (ㅐ), 어 (ㅓ), and 오 (ㅗ), respectively. Of course, there are no Korean names like 타어오, but a lot of English speakers will not know it.
5. When it is difficult to differentiate between Korean and Japanese names, ***oo* might be pronounced as /oː/** because [Japanese people romanize ō as oh, oo, or ou for their passports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hepburn_romanization). In another similar situation, using *u* might be a problem because Japanese u (う) sounds different from Korean u (우); like a consonant, a vowel is a phoneme. The pronunciation of Japanese u is one between 으 and 우.
6. **If one has 우 as her/his family name and her/his family member (usually, her/his father or her/his sibling) has already got a passport with 우 romanized as *Woo*,** she/he needs to use *Woo* as her/his romanized family name to obtain her/his passport. [This is **mandatory**](https://www.passport.go.kr/new/use/roma_allow.php).
7. If 우 is either your first name or your last name, a single-letter romanization like *u* can cause trouble as [this](https://www.quora.com/Can-you-have-a-single-letter-as-a-legal-first-name) suggests. For example, a lot of English websites disallow single-character names.

Comment: With respect to the first point, I think it's possible the character 노 has it's roots in a Chinese character that can be written as Roh (similar to how old names with 이 used to be written as Rhee, eg 이승만). Also the North Korean state news paper is named 로동 신문, which I believe is their version of 노동. 우 being written as Woo might have similar roots.